# Passing parameter through notifyTopics in Struts2?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, subscribe

Situation:

Before deleting an entity from a list through notifyTopics it asks for confirmation.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {

        $.subscribe("/confirmDeleteArticle",function(event,data) {
            if ( confirm('<s:text name="article.msg.confirm.delete" />') ) {
                return true;
             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }
        },null);
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <s:url id="disableLink" action="ArticleAction-delete" namespace="/secure/article" includeParams="none">
        <s:param name="id" value="%{id}" />
    </s:url>
    <sj:a href="%{disableLink}" targets="maintarget" onClickTopics="/confirmDeleteArticle">
        <img src="../images/icons/cross.png" alt="<s:text name="global.delete" />" title="<s:text name="global.delete" />"/>
    </sj:a>
```

Problem:

I would like to pass a parameter about the title of the entity to confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this same problem for almost about 2 hours. And adding
escapeAmp="false" attribute in struts2-url-tag fixes the issue.

e.g.

```
<s:url id="link_pactpersonal" action="pactpersonal" escapeAmp="false">
    <s:param name="nparam" value="%{'nvalue'}"></s:param>
    <s:param name="option" value="%{option}"></s:param>
    <s:param name="idstu" value="%{idstu}"></s:param>
    <s:param name="accordValue" value="%{accordValue}"></s:param>
</s:url>

<sj:div targets="divPersonal"
            id="divPersonal"
            name="divPersonal"
            indicator="indicator"
            href="%{link_pactpersonal}"
            reloadTopics="reloadPersonalDiv"
            formIds="hiddenForm"
            >
    </sj:div>
```

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago. But this is not really what I am asking. I would like to pass parameters thru /confirmDelete topic.

For your problem: add "struts.url.escapeAmp=false" to your struts.properties and it will set this property on all urls.